# Add jeninks local user readonly account when using Global GitHub OAuth Sec

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-github-plugin

How can I add a limited access account for jenkins automation when I'm using Global GitHub OAuth Settings?

I'm using GitHub OAth for login to jenkins and I have python jenkinsapi scripts that I want to run as a user with read only access.  At present, all my users are github users.

I can create a github account without access to my repositories and then limit that accounts access to jenkins but this seems cumbersome.

Is there a way to use multiple security realms or to create local users?

It seems that when jenkins contains a local user, that the plugin uses this first ([plugin-source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-oauth-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/GithubSecurityRealm.java#L639))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at Manage Jenkins->Configure Global Security, you can see that you can select only one security realm.

I would say, for Jenkins use create a github service account specifically that user can be restricted to just a few repositories. You can also look at [matrix based security](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security) or [project based matrix security](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) if you want to restrict authorization further

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out going with LDAP is a better fix for us.  LDAP let's me manage users more easily.  alas, it'd be great if the groups worked.